# How to set second input field date according first enterd date

Tags: jquery

I'm adding first input date and after i want second input field should automatically get the date according the first date.
There should be one year difference.
Here is my code.

```js
$('#one').change(function() { 
    var currentval = $('#one').val();
    var my =  currentval.split('-');
    var dy = parseInt(my[0])+1+'-'+my[1]+'-'+parseInt(my[2]-1);
 $('#two').val(dy);
```

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="one" name="one"placeholder="Please enter the value"> 

<input type="date" class="form-control" id="two" name="two"placeholder="Please enter the value">
```

Here is my date.
if i select first date e.g 02/03/2020 so second date should be like 01/03/2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done with HTML5 `input type="date"` with help of JavaScript to check `leap year` for *February month days count* & set values in actual format into next input field with `min attribute`.
I hope below snippet will help you lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#one').on('change input', function() { 
    var datearray = $(this).val().split("-");
    var d = parseInt(datearray[2]) - 1;
    var day = ('0' + d).slice(-2);
    var month = ('0' + parseInt(datearray[1])).slice(-2);
    var year = datearray[0];
    // Chek Leap Year
    var leapYear = ((parseInt(year)+1) % 100 === 0) ? ((parseInt(year)+1) % 400 === 0):((parseInt(year)+1) % 4 === 0); 
    //Without Leap Year Feb(28 days)
    if (day=="00" && month=="03" && leapYear!=true) {
      day = "28";
      month = "02";
    }
    //With Leap Year Feb(29 days)
    else if(day=="00" && month=="03" && leapYear==true){
      day = "29";
      month = "02";
    }
    //For 1st Day + 1st Month to set same year last month
    else if(day=="00" && month=="01"){
      day = "31";
      month = "12";
      year = (parseInt(year)-1)
    }
    // For 1st day selection in Feb
    else if(day=="00" && month=="02"){
      day = "31";
      month = "01";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in April
    else if(day=="00" && month=="04"){
      day = "31";
      month = "03";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in May
    else if(day=="00" && month=="05"){
      day = "30";
      month = "04";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in June
    else if(day=="00" && month=="06"){
      day = "31";
      month = "05";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in July
    else if(day=="00" && month=="07"){
      day = "30";
      month = "06";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in Aug
    else if(day=="00" && month=="08"){
      day = "31";
      month = "07";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in Sep
    else if(day=="00" && month=="09"){
      day = "31";
      month = "08";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in Oct
    else if(day=="00" && month=="10"){
      day = "30";
      month = "09";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in Nov
    else if(day=="00" && month=="11"){
      day = "31";
      month = "10";
    }
    // For 1st day selection in Dec
    else if(day=="00" && month=="12"){
      day = "30";
      month = "11";
    }
    var minDate = ((parseInt(year)+1)+"-"+month+"-"+ day);
    $('#two').val(minDate); 
    $('#two').attr('min', minDate); 
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6 com-md-4">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="one" name="one"placeholder="Please enter the value">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 com-md-4">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="two" name="two"placeholder="Please enter the value">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please pick the first day of the date so you will see it is not working

Comment: @server Please check updated snippet so I have done without any `datepicker` plugin... :-)

Comment: @server Welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. You didn't close the brackets.

The second thing you need to add `0` for digits less than 9 in date.

Please see this example

```js
$('#one').change(function() { 
    var currentval = $('#one').val();
    var my =  currentval.split('-');
    var temp = my[2]-1;
    var dy = parseInt(my[0])+1+'-'+(my[1])+'-'+(('0' +temp).slice(-2));
    $('#two').val(dy);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="one" name="one"placeholder="Please enter the value"> 

<input type="date" class="form-control" id="two" name="two"placeholder="Please enter the value">
```

**NOTE:** Input type `date` will not work in all browsers. You should use any jquery date-picker plugin instead.

Comment: if you select first day of the month then you can see second date is not displaying

Comment: pick the day first upto 10 days so you will see it is not working. when selecting 11 in from the date then only it is working

Comment: I have made some changes, could you please check again?

Comment: still not working... please select the first day of the date. it will not display any date on other side.

Comment: It will not work for it. That's why I suggested you use a jquery plugin. It will manage all the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has just a syntax error. You have to close the `$('#one').on('change', function(){ /*your code*/});`. Either You can achive this using bootstrap-datepicker library

```js
//Date picker
    $('#startDatePicker').datepicker({
        format: 'MM dd, yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        endDate: "today",
        maxDate: "today",
        todayBtn: "linked"
    }).on('changeDate', function () {
        var tmp = date2 = $('#startDatePicker').datepicker('getDate');
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate());
        $('#endDatePicker').datepicker('setStartDate', date2);
        date2.setDate(tmp.getDate() + 365);
        $('#endDatePicker').datepicker('setDate', date2);
    });
    $('#endDatePicker').datepicker({
        format: 'MM dd, yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: "linked"
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="startDatePicker">Start Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="startDate" class="form-control" value="" readonly id="startDatePicker" />
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <label for="endDatePicker">End Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="endDate" class="form-control" value="" readonly id="endDatePicker" />
</div>
```

Comment: Will you please customize by giving js script because it is supporting bootstrap it disturbing other things also.

Comment: Just remove the bootstraps `css` & `js`